# Google-Big Query with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-bigquery

i am kind of new with google apis and JavaScript,

Does any one have a example or a tutorials of how i can connect with the Google-Big Query api using JavaScript and load data from the sample tables to a simple HTML page.

Thanks in advance for this.

Comment: i have been been able to connect to the google "short-url-api" and test it, now I am trying to connect with bigquery and try to run a few queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // User Submitted Variables
      var project_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
      var client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';

      var config = {
        'client_id': client_id,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
      };

      function showProjects() {
        var request = gapi.client.bigquery.projects.list();
        request.execute(function(response) {     
            $('#result_box').html(JSON.stringify(response, null));
        });
      }

      function showDatasets() {
        var request = gapi.client.bigquery.datasets.list({
          'projectId':'publicdata'
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {     
            $('#result_box').html(JSON.stringify(response.result.datasets, null));
        });
      }

      function runQuery() {
       var request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
          'projectId': project_id,
          'timeoutMs': '30000',
          'query': 'SELECT TOP(repository_language, 5) as language, COUNT(*) as count FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] WHERE repository_language != "";'
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {     
            console.log(response);
            $('#result_box').html(JSON.stringify(response.result.rows, null));
        });
      }

      function auth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
            gapi.client.load('bigquery', 'v2');
            $('#client_initiated').html('BigQuery client initiated');
            $('#auth_button').fadeOut();
            $('#projects_button').fadeIn();
            $('#dataset_button').fadeIn();
            $('#query_button').fadeIn();
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>BigQuery + JavaScript Example</h2>
    <button id="auth_button" onclick="auth();">Authorize</button>
    <div id="client_initiated"></div>
    <button id="projects_button" style="display:none;" onclick="showProjects();">Show Projects</button>
    <button id="dataset_button" style="display:none;" onclick="showDatasets();">Show datasets</button>
    <button id="query_button" style="display:none;" onclick="runQuery();">Run Query</button>
    <div id="result_box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code, I managed to create something similar, but not simple as this.

Is there anyway we can disable the authorisation pop-up(not with the "immediate : false"), so an external user can query from our dataset without having to login with their gmail account,

Answer (score 1):

fyi, you may want to try the JavaScript library available here:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/libraries

Comment: Thanks for the link, i have been following those samples. and those seem to work fine, but i am unable to query from the bigquery api.