# OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-bigquery

I have been working with Google-bigquery and JavaScript for a little time now, after getting  some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448789/google-big-query-with-javascript), something i realised is that the you require your Google login details associated with the project to authorise and achieve what your trying to do.

**What i am trying to achieve:-**
Allow users to visit my page, and view the data. For example i may show some public data based on weather forecast, so i do not require any users authentication,

Currently for research & development purposed i am using I am using **OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications**, i want to get rid of this as we don't need any user data, apart from having my project client-id email-id etc...

I have read on **[OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)**, and there don't seem to be any support for JavaScript so the end-user doesn't have to be involved.

Is there any solution to this or a safe quick fix, i have tried changing the config code from this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448789/google-big-query-with-javascript) to see what happens but no luck -

```
var config = {
            'client_id' : 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            "iss" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
            "scope" : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
            "aud" : "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "exp" : 1328554385,
            "iat" : 1328550785
        };
```

What am i missing in here.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice, i have been struggling for a very loong time with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no way to hide a client secret in client-side JavaScript code, there is no way to authorize a client-side JavaScript application to use BigQuery via a server-to-server OAuth flow.

The only solution in this case is to use a server side proxy for your API calls from the JavaScript application. Here's a snippet below of how you could proxy query calls via AppEngine (note: the code below is open to any user, it does do any check to make sure the calls are being run through your particular JavaScript client).

```
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

# BigQuery API Settings
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
PROJECT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXX' # REPLACE WITH YOUR Project ID

# Create a new API service for interacting with BigQuery
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)


class StartQueryHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    query_string = self.request.get('query')
    jobCollection = bigquery_service.jobs()
    jobData = {
      'configuration': {
        'query': {
          'query': query_string,
        }
      }
    }
    try:
      insertResponse = jobCollection.insert(projectId=PROJECT_ID,
                                            body=jobData).execute()
      self.response.headers.add_header('content-type',
                                       'application/json',
                                       charset='utf-8')
      self.response.out.write(insertResponse)
    except:
      self.response.out.write('Error connecting to the BigQuery API')


class CheckQueryHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, job_id):
    query_job = bigquery_service.jobs()
    try:
      queryReply = query_job.getQueryResults(projectId=PROJECT_ID,
                                             jobId=job_id).execute()
      self.response.headers.add_header('content-type',
                                       'application/json',
                                       charset='utf-8')
      self.response.out.write(queryReply)
    except:
      self.response.out.write('Error connecting to the BigQuery API')


application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/startquery(.*)', StartQueryHandler),
                                     ('/checkquery/(.*)', CheckQueryHandler)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```