# BigQuery similarity to "signed urls"

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-bigquery

I have the following use case in BigQuery:

- A non-trusted user will be querying a BigQuery table. Let's say the query is `SELECT * FROM [bigquery.table123]`.
- The query will return a large amount of data, let's say 200MB, which will then be displayed in the user's browser.

Our goal is to provide the most efficient way to get the 200MB data into the user's browser (and the worst way seems to do two trips instead of one -- from BQ to our server and then (compressed) to the client). I think the solution for this would probably be to enable the end (non-trusted) user to get something like a "signed-url" to perform the query directly from their browser to BigQuery. The flow would then be like this:

- User issues query to our backend.
- Authentication is done and a signed url is generated and passed back into javascript.
- The client then sends the signed url and the data is loaded directly into the browser.
- Only that exact query that has been authorized may be performed, and no other queries could be done (for example, if the client copied any tokens from the javascript)

I would never, ever want the end user to know the ProjectId or Table Name(s) that they are querying.

Is something like this possible to do in BigQuery? Here is an example of a similar need in [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). Here is an example of an authenticated/trusted user doing this in browser: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/browseRows.js or . https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509425/651174, but is there a way to do this in-browser for a non-trusted user?

Comment: why not to use two nested authorized views to accomplish this?  you provide user with "public" view that is view off of "private" view which is view off of real data. both views are authorized, so user never see what real data is used and has access to only "public" view

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant that sounds like an interesting approach. Could you please explain in an answer how that would be done, and how we'd prevent users from being able to issue queries that we haven't pre-authorized?

Comment: per your ask  - added as an answer with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an option that involves two levels of authorized views. This allows to shield not only underlying data from end user - but also hides what exactly data is being used

Let's assume data is in DatasetA. Below steps explain the logic

1. Create InternalView in DatasetB - this one will target real data from DatasetA.
2. Make InternalView as Authorized View for DatasetA
3. Create PublicView in DatasetC - this one will target InternalView
4. Make PublicView as Authorized View for DatasetB
5. Give users read access to DatasetC

Users will be ale to run PublicView which will actually be running PrivateView against readl data.
Meantime, users will not be able to see the definition of PrivateView thus will never know `ProjectId or Table Name(s) that they are querying`, etc.

Note: this does not address `how we'd prevent users from being able to issue queries that we haven't pre-authorized?` part of your question but I am adding my answer as you asked me to do

Meantime - at least theoretically - you can embed some logic into your PrivateView, which will be querying some internal metatable with info which user and when allowed to get result. Assuming that such meta-table will be managed by your backend based on authentication/token or whatever else you have in mind

Below is **simplified** and brief outline of that approach

```
#standardSQL
WITH `projectA.datasetA.table` AS (
  SELECT 'data1' col UNION ALL
  SELECT 'data2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'data3'
), `projectA.datasetA.applicationPermissions` AS (
  SELECT 'user1@gmail.com' user UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2@gmail.com'
), `projectA.datasetB.privateView` AS (
  SELECT d.* 
  FROM `projectA.datasetA.table` d
  CROSS JOIN `projectA.datasetA.applicationPermissions` p
  WHERE LOWER(user) = LOWER(SESSION_USER()) 
), `projectA.datasetC.publicView` AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `projectA.datasetB.privateView`
)
SELECT *
FROM `projectA.datasetC.publicView`
```

If `user1@gmail.com` or `user2@gmail.com` will run below query

```
SELECT *
FROM `projectA.datasetC.publicView`
```

they will get below result

```
Row col  
1   data1    
2   data2    
3   data3
```

while if `user3@gmail.com` will run same very query - result will be

```
Row col  
Query returned zero records.
```

Obviously, you can extend your meta-table (applicationPermissions) with for example timeframe during which user will be allowed to get result (respective lines to check time conditions will need to be added to `projectA.datasetB.privateView` )

Comment: great, thanks for this answer. Could you please provide a link in the BQ docs to creating Private Views, as in this part: `Meantime - at least theoretically - you can embed some logic into your PrivateView, which will be querying some internal metatable with info which user and when allowed to get result. ` ?

Comment: sorry for confusion if any - let me clarify 1) When I referenced PrivateView - I did not mean view of Type Private - I just meant it as a abstract name reflecting that definition of that view will not be available to end users 2) by internal metadata - I meant your application's data that you will be manage based on backend authentication, etc.  using for example `SESSION_USER()` function in conjunction with for example token you mentioned in your question 3) obviously - this is just direction and I doubt there is a link in documentation that directly reflects this approach